# mouseover() and mouseout() makes the overlay and control panel flick

Tags: jquery, mouseover, flicker, mouseout

I'm using the following code but when I have my pointer over the image, the overlay and the controls flickers. I have tested `mouseenter()` and `hover()` but it just flickers with these too.

```
$('.image-photo').mouseover(function() {
    $('.image-photo-overlay').show();
    $('.image-photo-controls').show();
});

$('.image-photo').mouseout(function() {
    $('.image-photo-overlay').hide();
    $('.image-photo-controls').hide();
});
```

Live demo: *link removed because I got it worked thanks to the user undefined*

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nothing flickers in FF and Chrome. What browser you're using? (btw, the `show hide` is a user-experience-killer and easy-doable in pure CSS)

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. I have added undefined's solution and therefor it worked. I have now added another overlay that are only over the image and not the whole content. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the wrapper element, when elements are shown, the `mouseout` event is triggered.

```
$('.background').hover(function() {
    $('.image-photo-overlay, .image-photo-controls').toggle();
});
```

Other option is using CSS `pointer-events` property:

```
.image-photo-overlay, .image-photo-controls {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
$('.image-photo').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I have the same issue with that solution too :/ Your edit worked better but I want to only trigger the hover effect when you have the pointer over the image. Not the entire background.

Comment: One problem though. How can I interact with the control panel on mouse over without the flickers?

Comment: @ErikEdgren You can listen to the `mouseenter` triggered for `.image-photo` element for showing overlays, and `mouseleave` of the overlayes for hiding them.